# Differentiation help (lots of square roots)

Tags: calculus

help finding the first derivative of this question:
$y=\sqrt{ 1 + \sqrt{ 1+\sqrt{1+8x}}}$

I get confused, is it meant to be done implicitly or is it just a really long chain rule?

Comment: Joanne, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for how to typeset equations here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is a long chain rule indeed:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+8x}}}} \cdot \frac d{dx} \left(1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+8x}} \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+8x}}}}\cdot \frac 1{2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+8x}}} \cdot \frac d{dx} \left(1+\sqrt{1+8x} \right) \\
&= \cdots
\end{align}
Perhaps you can finish the rest?

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely something that can be done with a really long chain rule.

$y=(((1+8x)^\frac{1}{2}+1)^\frac{1}{2}+1)^\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}(((1+8x)^\frac{1}{2}+1)^\frac{1}{2}+1)^\frac{-1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}((1+8x)^\frac{1}{2}+1)^\frac{-1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}(1+8x)^\frac{-1}{2}*8$